# Nelder mead isn't converging (scipy). Why is there only one initial point?

Tags: python, math, optimization, scipy

Here is a minimal reproducible example. If I set `x_0` to `0`, it seems that the optimiser is not able to move from it. If I set `x_0` to `10`, it converges to the global minimum. Any idea of what that is? Is it linked to how the [Nelder-Mead algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) work?

I get that it's probably stuck and terminates before converging and that optimisers are sometimes sensitive to initial guess but **I find this hard to check because we only give one initial point and the Nelder-Mead algorithm starts with (number of dimensions + 1) points so here we should be starting with two points??** Evidently, we only give one initial guess to SciPy, so my question is: **what second point does SciPy take and why does that lead to non-convergence if I use `x0 = 0`?**

With `x_0 = 0`

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds


def func(x):
    return ((x - 1000) ** 2 + (x - 10000) ** 2) + 440 ** (3 / 2) * np.sqrt(x)


x0 = np.array([0])
x_bounds = Bounds(0, 25000)
res = minimize(func, x0, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6, bounds=x_bounds)
print("Best:", res.x)
print("Loss:", func(res.x[0]))
```

Output:

```
Best: [0.]
Loss: 101000000.0
```

With `x0 = 10`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds


def func(x):
    return ((x - 1000) ** 2 + (x - 10000) ** 2) + 440 ** (3 / 2) * np.sqrt(x)


x0 = np.array([10])
x_bounds = Bounds(0, 25000)
res = minimize(func, x0, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6, bounds=x_bounds)
print("Best:", res.x)
print("Loss:", func(res.x[0]))
```

Output:

```
Best: [5484.42156982]
Loss: 41183994.677765995
```

I couldn't find much on the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-neldermead.html#optimize-minimize-neldermead) of Nelder-Mead. Neither could I on the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) of minimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-nelder-mead-optimization-in-python/

"A starting point must be provided to the algorithm, which may be the endpoint of another global optimization algorithm or a random point drawn from the domain.

Given that the algorithm may get stuck, it may benefit from multiple restarts with different starting points.

The algorithm works by using a shape structure (called a simplex) composed of n + 1 points (vertices), where n is the number of input dimensions to the function."

The answer for why you are providing only one initial point is here:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/b5d8bab88af61d61de09641243848df63380a67f/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py#L743

So simplex is built from n + 1 points, and each of them are your starting point (replicated). So the number of dimensions is sth other than the number of the points.

Comment: So the first two points are: 0 & zdelt = 0.00025 if I understand well. Why would it be stuck? It should get that the second point is better than the first and should keep going towards bigger `x`s right ?

Comment: Oh I just realised func(0.00025) > func(0) so that's why it's stuck at 0, it's a local minimum !!